# Remove null from a json data (python)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, firebase-realtime-database

When I use the Rest API to download data from Firebase, it looks like this.

```json
{
  "Dataset1": [
    null,
    {
      "Key1": 1,
      "Key2": 2
    },
    {
      "Key1": 3,
      "Key2": 4
    }
  ],
  "Dataset2": [
    null,
    {
      "Key1": 1,
      "Key2": 2
    },
    {
      "Key1": 3,
      "Key2": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to remove the `null` value before saving the data to a file? I know the `null` exists because of how I designed my database, but it is too late for me to redesign the data now. I tried `is_not` but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's just the first element in each list. You could just use a simple dict comprehension for this if so:

```
{k: v[1:] for k, v in data.items()}
```

If not you could use this comprehension:

```
{k: [e for e in v if e != None] for k, v in data.items()}
```

Comment: When JSON is loaded in Python, `null` becomes `None`, so `e is not None` should be used in the 2nd solution.

Comment: I figured and I had that in my original answer. Although if you look at OP's comment he specifically said "null"

Comment: `null` is in the JSON text file and is JSON syntax.  When Python does `data = json.load()` on the file text text is converted to Python types, and it becomes `None`, so you're 2nd solution won't work.  Load the OP's data and try it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've stored nodes with sequentially incrementing keys in your database (i.e. "1", "2", "3"). When you do this, Firebase interprets it as an array structure, and coerces it to a (zero-based) array when you retrieve it. And since you have no node for index 0, it adds a `null` there.

To prevent this array coercion, store nodes with non-numeric keys, for example by prefixing each number with a short non-numeric value. Like "key1", "key2", "key3".

Also see:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: Actually great answer. Seems this is likely OP's issue.

Comment: Good idea. This is something i will do from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Dataset2 = list()
for data in Dataset:
    if data not null:
        Dataset2.append(data)
Dataset = Dataset2
del Dataset2
```